# Simple SSO in IIS7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, iis-7

I'm very new to web development in general so I need a push in the right direction here. I have developed a simple in-house solution for my company where all but one web page is for public access (from within the intranet) so I've enabled anonymous access to the site.

One page, however, is for some simple maintenance and I would like to implement a very vanilla-type SSO-scheme to avoid manual login for my users. My idea is to extract the user's Windows Identity and simply cross-check it with a list of accepted identities in a datastore.

The problem is that when I allow anonymous access for the web site I don't get the Windows id (through HttpContext.Request.LogonUserIdentity). What I get is "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR". But if I disable anonymous access I just get a redirection to a login page.

Is there any strategy/configuration I can use that would allow for anonymous access while also passing the users' Windows identity?

Comment: Do you need an Internet Explorer tag, or should this be applicable to all browsers?

Comment: Preferably IE 10/11 and Chrome. Other browsers are not supported by my company.

Comment: I asked because I understood the Windows Id to which you're referring only to work in IE--it's been a long time since I attempted anything like that though. Perhaps other browsers support it now.

Comment: Having enabled both Windows authentication and Anonymous access for the web site I get the same user identity from the request (IUSR) no matter which browser I use.

Comment: And: If I can only make this simple scheme work with IE then that's perfectly acceptable too.